# Radial Gradient ellipse doesnt work properly

Tags: html, css

I have a school project where i need to make a exact copy of a website.
The background is  a bit tricky because i need to  (what i think) add a radial ellipse but then with no sides or bottom, only the top.

when i try to make a ellipse i get a oval which covers all four sides (obviously) but i dont know hot to apply it to the top only.

can anyone help me out?

this is what is is supposed to look like

PLease pay attention to the background only

[image: Here is the background]

I already tried a ellipse and a normal radial gradient but i does not function how i want it to be.

this is the code i have

```
 background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse, white, lightgrey, lightgrey,  
#1b1b2e 
#1b1b2e);
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust your code like below:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(150% 150% at bottom center, white, lightgrey,  #1b1b2e, #1b1b2e);
}
```